# How to set up a WWAN Router using 20.04 Server

Tags: networking, server, usb-modem, router, wwan

I am trying to setup a home office server and WWAN router using Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 .  Rather confusingly the server edition is unable to detect & configure the USB WWAN modem during install, while the desktop edition can.  Worse, it seems like various command line networking tools that are needed for WWAN modems are not part of the server install.

Lastly it seems that there are critical differences with networking in 20.04 LTS so all the older how-tos are not helpful.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2443631&highlight=server  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: This is sorta helpful.  What I've done so far is tried to find all the packages for wwan service that are missing and then installed them with dpkg.  Unfortunately I think this is only half the battle and as Ubuntu Server does not have Network Manager already running, suddenly I'm wondering what unknown and unwanted consequences I'm going to be facing if I make it run.

Comment: Server edition uses netplan, not Network Manager. See the example .yaml files here: /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `iwconfig` and also: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`